# Using a year's natural number value in a SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

How do I query wikidata for a list of scientists that died in a prime-numbered year, and also were born in a prime-numbered year, using SPARQL? Here is what I have so far, which returns no results, and I'm assuming that's because people don't die in a number, but rather in a year...
Also missing is the UNION statement for those ***born*** in a prime-numbered year, but we can omit that for the sake of focus.

```
SELECT ?number ?scientist ?scientistLabel
WHERE
{
  ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008.
  ?scientist wdt:P106 wd:Q901.
  ?scientist wdt:P570 ?number
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " [AUTO_LANGUAGE].en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?number)
```

Here is the URL for this query entered into the Query Service: https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fnumber%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fnumber%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ49008.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ901.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP570%20%3Fnumber%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D.en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fnumber%29

Comment: what have you tried? I can't see a SPARQL query. Grepping the year out of a date is done via [`year`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-year) function. and no, there is no `isPrime` function or something similar in SPARQL.

Comment: edited to reflect what I've tried

Comment: ok, but death date is a date as the name suggest, or not? Did you try what I mentioned in the comment, i.e. use `year` function to get the year out of the date?

Comment: this query returns all prime number values smaller than the current year (you don't need more I guess): `select ?value {
  ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008.
  ?number wdt:P1181 ?value
          filter(?value <= year(now()))
  }`

Comment: just combine it with the year value of the death date

Comment: @AKSW, this should be a great answer!!

Comment: @StanislavKralin Well, the query itself seems to work: `SELECT ?deathYear ?scientist ?scientistLabel

WHERE
{
  {select ?value { ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008. ?number wdt:P1181 ?value filter(?value <= year(now())) }}

    
  ?scientist wdt:P106 wd:Q901.
  ?scientist wdt:P570 ?deathDate
             BIND(year(?deathDate) as ?deathYear)
             filter(?deathYear = ?value)
 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " [AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
order by asc(?deathYear) asc(?scientistLabel)
limit 100`

Comment: @StanislavKralin surprisingly, it's slower than expected given the low number of intermediate results.  Indeed, there will be a cartesian before the FILTER is applied.

Comment: The essence of this question is now resolved, and the current discussion has little to do with the problem I assumed I was having when I originally posted. I will therefore re-post with a new, more focused question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102725/make-filtering-people-by-birthyear-and-deathyear-criteria-more-performative-in-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make filtering people by birthYear and deathYear criteria more performative in SPARQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53102725/make-filtering-people-by-birthyear-and-deathyear-criteria-more-performative-in-s)