# Make filtering people by birthYear and deathYear criteria more performative in SPARQL query

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, wikidata

I want to find instances of scientists who both were born and died in prime-numbered years. Building on a previous discussion at [this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086466/using-a-years-natural-number-value-in-a-sparql-query), I devised the following query, which is unwieldy and times out:

```
SELECT ?birthYear ?deathYear ?scientist ?scientistLabel 
WHERE 
{ 
 {
  select ?value1
    { 
      ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008. 
      ?number wdt:P1181 ?value1 
      filter(?value1 < year(now())) 
    }
  }
  {
  select ?value2
    { 
      ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008. 
      ?number wdt:P1181 ?value2 
      filter(?value2 < ?value1)
    }
  }
  ?scientist wdt:P106 wd:Q901. 
  ?scientist wdt:P570 ?deathDate.
  ?scientist wdt:P569 ?birthDate
  BIND(year(?deathDate) as ?deathYear) 
  BIND(year(?birthDate) as ?birthYear)
  filter(?deathYear = ?value1)
  filter(?birthYear = ?value2)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language " [AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
} 
order by asc(?deathYear) asc(?scientistLabel) 
limit 100
```

I'm a SPARQL novice, but as far as I can tell, this will take pairs of prime-numbers and then see if anyone whose occupation is 'scientist' died on the year corresponding to the first, then if that person was born on the year corresponding to the 2nd.
Is there a way to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: subqueries are evaluated in bottom-up manner, i.e. in your second subquery `?value1` is not bound

Comment: Thanks! Naïvely reversing those two `select` substatements results in zero listings, though. I probably need even more basic guidance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your query:

1. One can't pass values into subquery in such a way (see [*Bottom Up Semantics*](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Bottom_Up_Semantics)).
2. Values of `wdt:P1181` are `xsd:decimal`s, whereas `year()` returns `xsd:integer`s. One is forced to use `FILTER(?birthYear = ?value)` which is less performative and less optimizable than simple joins. It seems that Blazegraph has to materialize solutions prematurely.

Hence, your query should be:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?scientist ?scientistLabel ?birthYear ?deathYear {
  {
    SELECT (xsd:integer(?value1) as ?birthYear) { 
      ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008. 
      ?number wdt:P1181 ?value1 
      FILTER(?value1 < year(now())) 
    }
  }
  {
    SELECT (xsd:integer(?value2) AS ?deathYear) { 
      ?number wdt:P31 wd:Q49008. 
      ?number wdt:P1181 ?value2 
      FILTER(?value2 < year(now()))
    }
  }
  ?scientist wdt:P106 wd:Q901.
  ?scientist wdt:P570 ?deathDate.
  ?scientist wdt:P569 ?birthDate.
  FILTER(isLiteral(?birthDate) && isLiteral(?deathDate))
  BIND(year(?deathDate) AS ?deathYear) 
  BIND(year(?birthDate) AS ?birthYear)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } 
} ORDER BY ASC(?birthDate) ASC(?deathDate)
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fscientist%20%3FscientistLabel%20%3FbirthYear%20%3FdeathYear%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fvalue1%29%20as%20%3FbirthYear%29%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fnumber%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ49008.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fnumber%20wdt%3AP1181%20%3Fvalue1%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fvalue1%20%3C%20year%28now%28%29%29%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fvalue2%29%20AS%20%3FdeathYear%29%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fnumber%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ49008.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fnumber%20wdt%3AP1181%20%3Fvalue2%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fvalue2%20%3C%20year%28now%28%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ901.%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FdeathDate.%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FbirthDate.%0A%20%20FILTER%28isLiteral%28%3FbirthDate%29%20%26%26%20isLiteral%28%3FdeathDate%29%29%0A%20%20BIND%28year%28%3FdeathDate%29%20AS%20%3FdeathYear%29%20%0A%20%20BIND%28year%28%3FbirthDate%29%20AS%20%3FbirthYear%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%20%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3FbirthDate%29%20ASC%28%3FdeathDate%29)

I've also added `FILTER(isLiteral(?birthDate))`, because values of `wdt:P1181` might be [unknown values](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Somevalue) (i. e. RDF blank nodes), in which case `BIND (year(?birthDate) AS ?birthYear)` projects the variable which is always unbound and matches everything in joins.

---

You could speed up the query even more using Blazegraph specific tricks:

- [reusable named subqueries](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/NamedSubquery)
- [query hints](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?scientist ?scientistLabel ?birthYear ?deathYear
   WITH {
    SELECT (xsd:integer(?value) AS ?year) {
      [] wdt:P31 wd:Q49008 ; wdt:P1181 ?value. 
      hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true.
      FILTER(?value  <= year(now()))
    }
  } AS %primes {
    # hint:Query hint:maxParallel 50 . 
    # hint:Query hint:chunkSize 250 . 
  { SELECT (?year AS ?birthYear)  { include %primes } }
  { SELECT (?year AS ?deathYear)  { include %primes } } 
  ?scientist wdt:P106 wd:Q901.
  ?scientist wdt:P570 ?deathDate.
  ?scientist wdt:P569 ?birthDate.
  FILTER (isLiteral(?deathDate) && isLiteral(?birthDate))
  BIND (year(?birthDate) AS ?birthYear)
  BIND (year(?deathDate) AS ?deathYear)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
} ORDER BY ASC(?birthYear) ASC (?deathYear)
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fscientist%20%3FscientistLabel%20%3FbirthYear%20%3FdeathYear%0A%20%20%20WITH%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%28xsd%3Ainteger%28%3Fvalue%29%20AS%20%3Fyear%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5B%5D%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ49008%20%3B%20wdt%3AP1181%20%3Fvalue.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArangeSafe%20true.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fvalue%20%20%3C%3D%20year%28now%28%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%20AS%20%25primes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3AmaxParallel%2050%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20hint%3AQuery%20hint%3AchunkSize%20250%20.%20%0A%20%20%7B%20SELECT%20%28%3Fyear%20AS%20%3FbirthYear%29%20%20%7B%20include%20%25primes%20%7D%20%7D%0A%20%20%7B%20SELECT%20%28%3Fyear%20AS%20%3FdeathYear%29%20%20%7B%20include%20%25primes%20%7D%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP106%20wd%3AQ901.%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP570%20%3FdeathDate.%0A%20%20%3Fscientist%20wdt%3AP569%20%3FbirthDate.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28isLiteral%28%3FdeathDate%29%20%26%26%20isLiteral%28%3FbirthDate%29%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28year%28%3FbirthDate%29%20AS%20%3FbirthYear%29%0A%20%20BIND%20%28year%28%3FdeathDate%29%20AS%20%3FdeathYear%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3FbirthYear%29%20ASC%20%28%3FdeathYear%29%20%20)

Comment: This is wonderful. I have learned a lot by looking at your code.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Nice solution by using the named query feature of Blazegraph. Maybe you should mention that in the answer, others might try this on DBpedia :D
Also interesting that there are some non literal values for birth date and death date - strange, but probably both are not declared as OWL data properties.